# Is this a Markov chain property

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For $A,B$ measurable sets and $(X_n)_n$ a Markov chain. Do any of the following properties hold?

$$P(X_2 \in B | X_1=x_1,X_0 \in A) = P(X_2 \in B|X_1=x_1)$$
or 
$$P(X_2 \in B|X_1 \in A,X_0=x_0) = P(X_2 \in B|X_1 \in A)?$$

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: The fact that the quickly accepted answer to this unmotivated question is as wrong as can be, is, in a way, highly satisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both follow almost trivially from the definition.